# Search with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a `PowerShell` script that will search for both *files* and *folders* of the **same name**.  I'm able to search and find the folders, my question is, how do I incorporate searching for files in the same line with the code given below without using the file's extension as part of the search.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3" | 
  Select-Object DeviceID |
    ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem ($_.DeviceID + "\") -include "AA AA" -Recurse}
```

Comment: Sorry, Im still not sure what exactly you want to search. Can you provide some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're looking for files / folders either named literally `AA AA` or having `AA AA` as the filename *root*, followed by *any filename extension* (e.g., `AA AA.txt`).

If so, try this:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3" | 
  Select-Object DeviceID |
    ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem ($_.DeviceID + "\") -Recurse -Include 'AA AA', 'AA AA.*'}
```

Comment: If the file doesn't have an extension I presume it would not be found in this fashion?

Comment: @ssaviers: The `'AA AA`' argument should match file/folder names literally and fully named `AA AA`; the `'AA AA.*'` argument should cover file/folder names that have the same filename _root_, but with an (any) extension.

Comment: @Mklement0, Sorry for the misunderstanding I'm not use to this site just yet.  Thank you for the answer, it worked perfectly!!

Comment: @EVO No worries, we all were new here once; glad to hear it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. Remove the `-Recurse` if you don't want to down navigate sub folders and just search root contents of each drive found.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter DriveType = "3" |
    Select-Object DeviceID | ForEach-Object {
        Get-ChildItem ($_.DeviceID + '\') -Recurse | Where-Object {
            $_.Name -Match "AA AA"
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will match any file or folder whose name contains `AA AA` as a _substring_, which is likely too permissive.

Comment: Hello Mkement0   This works perfectly.  Thank you so much for you input :D

Comment: @EVO Please confirm you selected and commented to the correct answer depending on what worked for you.

Comment: I Applied this code.  Get-WmiObject win32_logicalDisk -Filter DriveType = "3" | Select-Object DeviceID | ForEach-Object {get-childitem ($_.DeviceID + '\')  -recurse  | ? {$_.name -Match "AA AA"}}  and it worked perfectly with what I was looking for.

Comment: Okay, but please do consider @mklement0 answer as it is likely less expensive than mine as he has made comment to.

Comment: Ok, I thought I was answering to his answer...    Thank you :D